# Converting csgo_items.txt to array to show in table

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I would like to parse the following text in PHP and show it in a table, since I need to lookup IDs often and I do not like to search through a file often.
It looks like this

```
"1"
{
    "name"      "weapon_deagle"
    "prefab"        "weapon_deagle_prefab"
    "item_quality"      "normal"
    "baseitem"      "1"
    "default_slot_item"     "1"
    "item_sub_position"     "secondary4"
}
"2"
{
    "name"      "weapon_elite"
    "prefab"        "weapon_elite_prefab"
    "item_quality"      "normal"
    "baseitem"      "1"
    "default_slot_item"     "1"
    "item_sub_position"     "secondary1"
}
```

I tried to parse these with explode and "}" as delimiter, but it always gives me weird results.
I heard of doing this with RegEx, but I am not sure about that.

My tries:

```
$items = file_get_contents('items.txt');
$arr = explode("}", $items);
```

Is the text maybe already some format I could parse? Or is it a custom one?

Comment: wts d expected output?

Comment: I would like to have an array with many subarrays ("1", "2") and the others as sub-sub-arrays ("name", "prefab")

Comment: Yes, I think. I tried to use that in PHP but it gives me one giant array without any subarrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
"(\d+)"(?=(?:[^{}]*{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*$)|"([^"]+)"\s+"([^"]+)"
```

Try this.Grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/65

```
$re = "/\"(\\d+)\"(?=(?:[^{}]*{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*$)|\"([^\"]+)\"\\s+\"([^\"]+)\"/s";
$str = "\"1\"\n{\n \"name\" \"weapon_deagle\"\n \"prefab\" \"weapon_deagle_prefab\"\n \"item_quality\" \"normal\"\n \"baseitem\" \"1\"\n \"default_slot_item\" \"1\"\n \"item_sub_position\" \"secondary4\"\n}\n\"2\"\n{\n \"name\" \"weapon_elite\"\n \"prefab\" \"weapon_elite_prefab\"\n \"item_quality\" \"normal\"\n \"baseitem\" \"1\"\n \"default_slot_item\" \"1\"\n \"item_sub_position\" \"secondary1\"\n}";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: I get this: Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) [3] => Array ( ) )